# How Do I Run Two Websites on Port 80 (accesible from 2 DNS records)

Tags: apache, dns, web, debian, port80

I want to run two websites on ONE apache installation running on Debian. I want both of my sites to be on port 80. They are both assigned to two different DNS records. When 123.456.78.901:80 is accessed from [www.mcpvp.net](http://www.mcpvp.net), I want it to go to Site A. When 123.456.78.901:80 is accessed from [www.pmcpvp.net](http://www.pmcpvp.net), I want it to go to Site B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use apache VirtualHost in order to redirect traffic coming from certain DNS records to certain folders on your server.

DigitalOcean's tutorial explains it well: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-8

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I just thought that no further explanation was needed because the tutorial covers exactly what he wants to do and it explains it for Debian

I thought that trying to give a short explanation on top of the link would be confusing because I'm not that good at explaining, but thanks for pointing it out anyway

Comment: You could take this oppurtinity and [edit] details into your answer. So when the link is inaccessible the solution might already be here serving value to future visitors.